# Ignore identical values in a specific column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, distinct-values

I have this query that works as it should. However, I am having a problem with the query returning identical int values under the [id2] column. I need help in only grabbing one instance of the value and ignoring the other. Basically grab a unique [id2]. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Also, if you need clarification let me know.

```
SELECT [id],[id1]
 ,[id2]
 ,[name]
 ,[date]
 ,[user]     
FROM [MyDatabase.table]
Where [date]>= dateadd(day,datediff(day,0,getdate()),-5)
ORDER BY [cid]
```

**Edit 1:**

```
id1       id2    name        time                user
6466    171477  item1 2012-10-10 07:08:48.000   user1
6469    171477  item1 2012-10-10 07:11:01.000   user1
6468    171477  item1 2012-10-10 07:10:37.000   user1
6465    171477  item1 2012-10-10 07:07:43.000   user1
6464    171477  item1 2012-10-10 07:06:58.000   user1
6467    171477  item1 2012-10-10 07:09:35.000   user1
6474    173026  item2 2012-10-10 10:20:21.000   user2
6478    173297  item3 2012-10-10 11:31:55.000   user3
6472    175445  item4 2012-10-10 07:18:17.000   user1
6460    175977  item5 2012-10-08 07:42:39.000   user4
6473    176253  item6 2012-10-10 10:18:21.000   user2
6471    176253  item6 2012-10-10 10:15:03.000   user2
6470    176253  item6 2012-10-10 10:14:34.000   user2
```

Should be:

```
id1     id2    name        time                user
6466    171477  item1 2012-10-10 07:08:48.000   user1
6474    173026  item2 2012-10-10 10:20:21.000   user2
6478    173297  item3 2012-10-10 11:31:55.000   user3
6472    175445  item4 2012-10-10 07:18:17.000   user1
6460    175977  item5 2012-10-08 07:42:39.000   user4
6473    176253  item6 2012-10-10 10:18:21.000   user2
```

Comment: If you have duplicates in that column, what about the other columns?  Please post a sample of your table, and a sample of what the output should look like

Comment: What logic decides which times to ignore and which times to include?  Your example makes it seem like your time and id1 fields are completely arbitrary.  Using id2 171477 as an example.  The time you chose isn't the earliest or latest for id2.  The id1 you chose is neither the lowest nor the highest for id2.

Comment: Ok, I just want the id2 column to display only one instance of 171477. The time and id1 really have no barring on the output.

Comment: Then why not just `select distinct id2, name, user from ..... ` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
;WITH tbl_online AS (
SELECT [id],[r_id]
 ,[cid]
 ,[name]
 ,[date]
 ,[user] ,ROW_NUMBER () OVER (
PARTITION BY [cid] ORDER BY [cid] ) AS Rnum
FROM [MyDatabase.table]
Where [date]>= dateadd(day,datediff(day,0,getdate()),-5)   )
SELECT *  FROM tbl_online WHERE Rnum !>1
ORDER BY [cid]
```

Comment: Why would one use the non-standard, proprietary (to SQL-Server) and confusing `Rnum !> 1` when one can use the standard and simple `Rnum = 1`, is beyond my comprehension.

Answer (score 2):

You may need to adjust the `ORDER BY` part below depending on how you want to choose which row to return.

```
WITH cteRowNum AS (
    SELECT id1, id2, name, time, user,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY id2 ORDER BY time) AS RowNum
        FROM MyDatabase.Table
)
SELECT id1, id2, name, time, user
    FROM cteRowNum
    WHERE RowNum = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be looking for the earliest record of the list for a given (id2, name) and the following query would retrieve them:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM 
    YourTable a
    JOIN 
    (
        SELECT MIN(id1) as id1, id2, name FROM YourTable GROUP BY id2, name
    ) as b
    ON a.id1 = b.id1
```

Comment: At first glance yes... but id2 has another value of 6464 further down that is lower than the one he picked??

Comment: Thanks for your comment @RThomas, another guess that he is looking for the earliest record based on (id2, name) tuple :)